# looping over a txt file in order to place it into dynamic array

Tags: c

Im trying to create 2d array using calloc and place there sequences from txt file. the file is built with sequence name and the next line is the sequence itself. for some reason my loop runs only once and extracts only one sequence to seq array.
input ex(each is a new line)

```
seq1
GATTACAATATT
seq2
CTTTGCATTT
```

here is some of my code: (100 is max for seq number and for chars in line of text)

```
char ** seq = (char **) calloc(100,sizeof(char*));
int index=0;
char c;
char line[100];
int n=0;

while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL)
{
    char *pToArray = (char*) calloc(100 ,sizeof(char));
    n=0;

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && (c!='>'))
    {
        if(c!='\n' && c!='\r' && c!=' ')
        {
            pToArray[n++] = c;
        }
        if(c=='\n') //reallocating memory if the seq is too long
            pToArray = realloc(pToArray ,sizeof(pToArray) + sizeof(char)+1);
    }
    pToArray[n] = '\0';
    seq[index] = pToArray;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: How is `seq` defined?

Comment: `sizeof(pToArray)` is `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: You read into `line` but never use it. Is that on purpose? You should post an example of a small input file to better explain what the program is to do.

Comment: Why do you use `if(c=='\n')` as a condition for reallocating? The condition should rather be `if (n == current_size)`

Comment: example of input:
>seq1
GATTACAATATT

after line breaking there might be a broken seq

definition of seq:
    char ** seq = (char **) calloc(100,sizeof(char*));

Comment: @AKH Please edit your question and add the example of input there. Currently we can't see if there are any newlines in the input

Comment: notice that `fgetc` returns an **int** So `char c;` shall be `int c;` (this is needed for comparing with EOF)

Comment: If you read with `char line[100];` why are you allocating `100` chars instead of `strlen (line) + 1`?

Comment: I'd suggest first writing a function that reads one line of arbitrary length.